# CSS prevent child overflowing parent height

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS layout:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

nav {
  background-color: darkslateblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

main h2 {
  padding: 20px 20px 10px 20px;
}

#item-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}

#item-selector,
#item-viewer {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

#item-selector {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 250px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#item-viewer {
  flex: 1;
  height: 50vh;
}

.item {
  border: 3px solid darkslateblue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#item-viewer {
  border: 3px solid darkslateblue;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <h1>Header</h1>
</nav>
<main>
  <h2>Your items:</h2>
  <div id="item-wrapper">
    <div id="item-selector">
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="item-viewer">
      <p style="padding: 10px;">Select an item on the left to view more information</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

I want the scrollable div on the left to not exceed the height of the window. I have tried setting the height of `<body>` and `<html>` to `100vh` and adding `overflow: auto` and `overflow: hidden` to `body`, `html`, `#item-wrapper` and `#item-selector` but none of these worked. If I give `#item-selector` and explicit height then it works, but I want it to fill the remainder of the window height so this isn't ideal. I would like `#item-selector` to not exceed the height of the page and to scroll when its contents exceed its height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to apply `height` settings to *all*  parent elements, so `html` and  `body` and `#item-selector` get `height: 100%;`, and `main` has to get a calculated height value, which subtracts the height of the `nav` and `h2` elements from 100%. `height: calc(100% - 130px);` will approximately do that like in the snippet below, but you either would have to define exact height settings for `nav` and `h2`, or use javascript to get their actual heights.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
}

nav {
  background-color: darkslateblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}
main {
  height: calc(100% - 130px);

}
main h2 {
  padding: 20px 20px 10px 20px;
}

#item-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}

#item-selector,
#item-viewer {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

#item-selector {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 250px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
}

#item-viewer {
  flex: 1;
  height: 50vh;
}

.item {
  border: 3px solid darkslateblue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#item-viewer {
  border: 3px solid darkslateblue;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <h1>Header</h1>
</nav>
<main>
  <h2>Your items:</h2>
  <div id="item-wrapper">
    <div id="item-selector">
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="item-viewer">
      <p style="padding: 10px;">Select an item on the left to view more information</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

nav {
  background-color: darkslateblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 10vh;
}

main h2 {
  padding: 5px 20px 20px 20px;
}

#item-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  height:85vh;
}

#itemHeaderWrapper{
  height:5vh;
}

#item-selector,
#item-viewer {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

#item-selector {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 250px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#item-viewer {
  flex: 1;
  height: 50vh;
}

.item {
  border: 3px solid darkslateblue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#item-viewer {
  border: 3px solid darkslateblue;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <h1>Header</h1>
</nav>
<main>
  <div id='itemHeaderWrapper'>
    <h2>Your items:</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="item-wrapper">
    <div id="item-selector">
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p style="font-size:50px;">Item</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="item-viewer">
      <p style="padding: 10px;">Select an item on the left to view more information</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

In this code, I've wrapped the h2 tag in a div, id 'itemHeaderWrapper' which I've given a pre-defined height of 5vh. I've also set the height of the nav to 10vh. This means I can force the scrollable div on the left to have height 85vh and then scroll.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't want to have to manually set the height of everything.